# Auth0/Angular2-Jwt not working with Angular 5

Tags: angularjs, json, jwt, angular5, auth0

Angular2-JWT has a particular function I need to use in order to Show/Hide links based on the logged user token being stored in localStorage.

tokenNotExpired();

I have been looking for alternative ways on implementing the conditional statements showing nav-links IF token is in localStorage but doesn't seem to work.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
 import {FlashMessagesModule} from 'angular2-flash-messages';
 import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
 @Injectable()
 export class AuthService{
   authToken:null;
   user:any;
    isLoggedin: boolean = false;
   constructor(private http:Http) { }



   isLoggedIn() {
     if (localStorage.getItem("id_token") == null) {
         this.isLoggedin = false;
         console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
         return this.isLoggedin;
     }
     else {
       console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
         return true;
     }
   }
```

I can't seem to figure why it doesn't work correctly.
Maybe I am missing something.

```
<ul class="nav-l" NgClass="{'invisible':isLoggedIn()===true}">
  <li class="nav-link" NgIf="isLoggedIn()"  [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="'/home'">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-link" NgIf="isLoggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="'/about'">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-link" NgIf="isLoggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="'/feature'">Features</a></li>
  <li class="nav-link" NgIf="isLoggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="'/contact'">Contact</a></li>
```

In the HTML above I have tried two different methods of hiding them (NgClass condition & NgIf condition).

Comment: should not be there *ngIf instead of NgIf? and NgClass seems to be wrong too

Comment: I thought so too, but I was changing them and alternating because they either way it wasn't working for me any way I put a condition

Comment: the navbar component was the issue, the isLoggedIn() is in the auth.service and for whatever reason it wouldn't pass to navbar, so I moved the function into the navbar.component.ts and it now works!! Thanks for the advice anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

The important point is to know which schema changes frequently, eg. user, company or project...

If a schema does not change frequently, you can embed it in its parent schema but embedding data too hard to manipulate, otherwise you can embed its ids in a new field.

You can use [child referencing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/) if your UserSchema change frequently.

```
const CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    ....
    userIds: [1, 2, 3]
})
```

Or [parent referencing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/) if your CompanySchema change frequently.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    ....
    companyId: 1
})
```

In this one, companyId can be `null`.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  you did help a lot. it's making a lot more sense now.